# "The current configured Flutter SDK is not known to be fully supported. Please update your SDK and restart IntelliJ"

Tags: flutter, sdk

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve since last week, I've been searching about this issue and nothing works. I tried to reinstall the flutter and didn't work aswell. The image below is the first issue I have.

[image]

Then I went to "Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Upgrade" and it shows me this message:

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color upgrade
fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs: ...
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs: ...
  Command: git fetch --tags
Process finished with exit code 1
```

And when I tap to "Run 'main.dart'", it shows me this message:

```
fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs: ...
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Running "flutter pub get" in olx...                             



The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.

Because carousel_pro 1.0.0 requires Flutter SDK version >=1.2.0 <2.0.0 and no versions of carousel_pro match >1.0.0 <2.0.0, carousel_pro ^1.0.0 is forbidden.
So, because olx depends on carousel_pro ^1.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because olx depends on carousel_pro ^1.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

What could I do to fix these issues?
(Thanks for listening :)

Comment: what your erros is saying is carousel_pro depends on version >=1.2.0 <2.0.0, but you must be using higher version of the flutter sdk, which version of flutter are you using ?

Comment: "fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs: ..." is never a good sign.  It means your flutter install is no longer a valid git archive.

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is raised due to Flutter SDK version because it is unknown.

These are some steps that I have followed to solve this problem

1. Run the following git command into your terminal

   => git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

   (this command will clone a flutter folder which contains latest version of Flutter SDK. get more info about SDK - [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=linux))
2. after cloning, we just need to move cloned folder to our default location of flutter SDK.

   In my case path of flutter SDK is as follows(ubuntu) -

   => file:///home/bulbul/snap/flutter/common/flutter

I replaced the last flutter folder with the folder which I have cloned before.

then I ran the "flutter --version" command for getting the version of flutter SDK and it gave me the latest version of flutter SDK and the problem was solved.

It worked for me hopefully It will work for you as well.
Happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest flutter SDK then check if the git is available from the command line using git --version. If it's not available from the command line android studio terminal then add git to system path variable and restart android studio.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).